# How to skip "Email" in login form so i can login.There's "Email" in register form and database but i dont want to delete it

Tags: java, android

In android studio im using SQLite
There's username,email,password in Register form
But there's only username and password i want to input in Login Form
to make it login into layout activity_home in activity : HomeActivity.java

the error's in this code (need 3 string):

```
  private void login(){
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String pass = etPass.getText().toString();

            if(db.getUser(username,pass)){
                session.setLoggedin(true);
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                finish();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong email/password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Full Code :

DBHelper.java

```
package com.demo.androidgudang;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 5/5/2016.
 */
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TAG = DbHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    public static final String DB_NAME = "myapp.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String USER_TABLE = "users";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASS = "password";

    /*
    create table users(
        id integer primary key autoincrement,
        email text,
        password text);
     */
    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_PASS + " TEXT);";

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USER_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String username, String email, String password) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, username);
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, email);
        values.put(COLUMN_PASS, password);

        long id = db.insert(USER_TABLE, null, values);
        db.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "user inserted" + id);
    }

    public boolean getUser(String username, String email, String pass){
        //HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String selectQuery = "select * from  " + USER_TABLE + " where " +
                COLUMN_USERNAME + " = " + "'"+username+"'" + " and " + COLUMN_EMAIL + " = " + "'"+email+"'" + " and " + COLUMN_PASS + " = " + "'"+pass+"'";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            return true;
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return false;
    }
}
```

HomeActivity.java

```
package com.demo.androidgudang;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnLogout;
    private Session session;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        session = new Session(this);
        if(!session.loggedin()){
            logout();
        }
        btnLogout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logout();
            }
        });
    }

    private void logout(){
        session.setLoggedin(false);
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
    }
}

Session.java

package com.demo.androidgudang;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 5/5/2016.
 */
public class Session {
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context ctx;

    public Session(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
        prefs = ctx.getSharedPreferences("myapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
    }

    public void setLoggedin(boolean logggedin){
        editor.putBoolean("loggedInmode",logggedin);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean loggedin(){
        return prefs.getBoolean("loggedInmode", false);
    }
}
```

RegisterActivity.java

```
package com.demo.androidgudang;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    TextView LoginDisini;
    private Button reg;
    private EditText etUsername, etEmail, etPass;
    private DbHelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        db = new DbHelper(this);
        reg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnReg);
        etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        etPass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPass);
        reg.setOnClickListener(this);
        LoginDisini = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LoginDisini);

        LoginDisini.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent loginHere = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(loginHere);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnReg:
                register();
                break;
            default:

        }
    }

    private void register(){
        String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
        String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        String pass = etPass.getText().toString();
        if(username.isEmpty() && email.isEmpty() && pass.isEmpty()){
            displayToast("Username/password field empty");
        }else{
            db.addUser(username,email,pass);
            displayToast("User registered");
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void displayToast(String message){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.demo.androidgudang;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button login;
    private EditText etUsername, etPass;
    private DbHelper db;
    private Session session;
    TextView RegisterDisini;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            db = new DbHelper(this);
            session = new Session(this);
            login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
            etPass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPass);
            login.setOnClickListener(this);
            RegisterDisini = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RegisterDisini);

            RegisterDisini.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent registerHere = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                    startActivity(registerHere);
                }
            });

            if(session.loggedin()){
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.btnLogin:
                    login();
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }

        private void login(){
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String pass = etPass.getText().toString();

            if(db.getUser(username,pass)){
                session.setLoggedin(true);
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                finish();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong email/password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the getUser method, add a *null* check for the *selectQuery* variable. First append the username and the password. Next if the email is given, append it to your query like following:

```
String selectQuery = "select * from  " + USER_TABLE + " where " +
            COLUMN_USERNAME + " = " + "'"+username+"'" + " and " + COLUMN_PASS + " = " + "'"+pass+"'";
if(email != null) 
        selectQuery += "and " + COLUMN_EMAIL + " = " + "'"+email+"'";
```

Then you can call the getUser by *db.getUser(username,null,pass)*.

Comment: Now it says "wrong username/password" when i press Login button.I still cannot login

Comment: I tried it with my changes and I can log in.
Don't you pass "null" instead of null? I don't know what else could be wrong.

If it still won't work, i uploaded the modified code here: [link](https://pastebin.com/3K9vxQ4W)

Comment: oh sorry its because i forgot to wipe data from my device because there's no column user in my SQLite device.Already solved my problem thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).